# How to search selected columns and find matching values

Tags: python, collections, openpyxl

From an input xlxs with one worksheet, I am collecting\mining data and creating\populating other worksheets in the same workbook. The worksheets contain multiple columns and will vary on each worksheet, so no fixed numbers of columns. I would like to search select columns with headers=username, for matching value and copy\create a new column with the common\matching values. For example:

| UserE | UserF | UserG | UserH | UserI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Group1 | Group2 | GroupA | Group1 | GroupC |
| GroupA | GroupA | Group2 | GroupA | GroupA |
| Group3 | GroupC | GroupB | Group2 | Group5 |
| Group2 | GroupF | GroupF | GroupG | Group2 |

will add a column 'match' to same worksheet and have below because those are the matching values that all the user have.

| match |
| --- |
| Group2 |
| GroupA |

I'm currently using Collections, csv,and openpyxl to produce the data that want to further mine.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the below code. Note that the program will read `input.xlsx` file `Sheet1` tab into a dataframe with assumption that the first row is the header, then find text that is common in each column and add a column to the right (one cell after the last column) with the word `match` and then the common strings one below the other. It will not touch/replace other tabs that might be present in the excel sheet. If there are no common strings, it will just have `match` as column header and no data below it.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

# Read data
df = pd.read_excel('input.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')

#For each column, find items that are common across all those columns
for i in range(df.shape[1]):
    if i == 0:
        match = set(df.iloc[:,i])
    else:
        match = match & set(df.iloc[:,i])

#Open using load_workbook so that no data is overwritten        
wb=load_workbook('input.xlsx')
ws=wb['Sheet1']
ws.cell(row=1,column=df.shape[1]+1).value = "match" #Add header row
for r_idx in range(len(match)):  #Add each item to last column below "match"
    ws.cell(row=r_idx+2, column=df.shape[1]+1).value=list(match)[r_idx]
#for c_idex, col in enumerate()
wb.save('input.xlsx')
```